# InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream when storing files in Blob column with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am starting to work on a project with spring boot and angular, and I have a database where I want to store a file. I have set this column to Blob, but after populating my database, with files, Spring does not want to work anymore.

Here is the error I got :

```
ERROR[0;39m [35m19036[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-7][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/alternance] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream]] with root cause  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[7]->com.alternance.dto.StageDTO["motivationFile"]->jdk.proxy2.$Proxy134["wrappedBlob"]->com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Blob["binaryStream"])
```

Here is the code that seems to be the problem :

```
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Stage {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Blob motivationFile;
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the error, this might take place when the jackson library (responsible for (de-)serializing the incoming and outgoing request/response objects from json to their respective objects and vice versa.

The problem you have might be one of two things, or both:

- You didn't set the property content-type when making a request to the backend
- You didn't annotate the motivationFile properly

When sending the request, be sure to use the form data content type.
For your entity class, you'd have to annotate the field with @Lob and optionally define what type of file you're saving.
E.g.

```java
//...
    @Lob
    @Column(... , columnDefiniton="BLOB")
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.BLOB)
    private Blob motivationFile
//...
```

Comment: Hi, for the Type annotation what should the import be from ? com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes.Type or org.hibernate.annotations.Type ?

Comment: I apologize, the up-to-date code should be
`@Lob @Column(... , columnDefinition="BLOB") private Blob motivationFile`

I have edited the answer to reflect this change.